# "The Titan submersible lowering into the sea": restrictions on intransitive sense of 'lower'

Tags: nautical-terms

NY Times caption on page 1 photo for 3 July 2023.

> "The Titan submersible lowering into the sea".

First time I've seen **lower** used intransitively to correspond to "(non-agentive) sinking, descending" ... which usage seems comparable to the 18th century use of "repairing" as in "The ship *was repairing* in dry dock" instead of "being repaired" as we would say nowadays.

Another example of intransitive **lower** is found in a 2014 report of the  [Offshore Technology ConferenceThusyanthan et al {p8}](https://www.cantab.net/users/Dr_Thusyanthan/45_2014_Dr_Thusyanthan_OTC25211_Challenges%20of%20Lowering%20a%20Live%20Subsea%20Buried%20Gas%20Pipeline%20by%206m_Dr%20N%20I%20Thusyanthan.pdf):

> This enabled the location of the pipeline, the trench profile and the
> tool to be viewed real-time by the tool operator. Figure 7 shows such
> a view of real time monitoring during one of the pipeline lowering
> passes. This real time monitoring was vital to ensure that the
> pipeline was lowering gradually and that the CFE tool was maintained
> sufficient distance away from the live gas pipeline.

Is this usage confined to nautical contexts?  Have you seen anything like "The mountaineer was lowering on a rope" ?  That is, not "lowering himself".

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147028/discussion-on-question-by-tim-the-titan-submersible-lowering-into-the-sea-res); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

The intransitive usage of the (relevant) verb **lower** is not too common; [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lower), for instance, gives it little prominence, and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lower_2) doesn't include it. But [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lower) gives it more prominence:

> *lower* [4 of 4] [verb (2)]
>
> lowered; lowering; lowers
>
> [intransitive verb]
>
> to move down, drop

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lower) also lists the intransitive usage last of all the verbal usages:

> *lower* [verb] [intransitive]
> 13. [5th of 5 verbal senses]:  to become lower; sink, fall, become reduced

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lower) includes the (to my ears not overly natural sounding) example

> • Houses have lowered in value recently.

and [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lower) overtly licenses only the 'shrink / get less' intransitive subsense, in its definitions:

> *lower* [verb]  ...
> 11. [of 11; last of 7 verbal usages] [intransitive]: to diminish or become less

So

- *The Titan submersible lowering into the sea*

is as grammatically acceptable a noun phrase as

- *The Titan submersible descending into the sea*

(if rather less usual. But the pull of the transitive usage (being lowered) is probably apt here; 'The brook lowers in early summer' ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lower)) sounds less appropriate to my ears. I'd go with ''The level of water in the brook falls in early summer'.)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147027/discussion-on-answer-by-edwin-ashworth-the-titan-submersible-lowering-into-the); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

The *OED* shows a number of intransitive uses of *lower*. A couple are nautical. One is rare. They all sound normal enough. Here they are, with selected samples from each entry:

> **lower**, *v.*
>
> **I.** Senses relating to height or position.
>
> **1.**
> **a.** *intransitive*. To descend, sink down; to move to a lower position. Also: †to cower, crouch (*obsolete*). Also *figurative* and
> with *down*.
>  <sub>1928     *Van Nuys* (Calif.) *News* 28
> Sept. 4/5     Again the plane lowered and I could read the
> name Van Nuys on a sign.</sub>
>  <sub>1992     *Disability
> Now* May 12 (advt.)      The siderests automatically fold in
> as the seat lowers.</sub>
>
> **b.** *intransitive*. To slope downwards. Also with *down*. Chiefly with *to, towards*.
>  <sub>1910     *Minnesota Rep.* 110
> 308     The tracks in the yard ran north and south upon a
> grade lowering towards the south.</sub>
>  <sub>1996     R.
> KOSHAL *Population Growth & Family Welfare Programme in India* i. 6
>    The plateau gradually lowers down towards the east.</sub>
>
> **2.**
> **b.** *intransitive*. *Nautical.* To let something down, esp. gradually; esp. to take down a sail or sails. Frequently with
> *away*.
>  <sub>1997     J. WHITE in P. H. Spectre *100 Boat Designs Reviewed* xxxvii. 122/1     Both boats show
> lazyjacks on the main to keep the sail up off the deck when lowering
> and furling.</sub>
>
> **c.** *intransitive*. *Nautical.* Of a small boat, as a whaleboat or lifeboat, or its passengers: to be let down to the water from a ship.
> Frequently with *away*.
>  <sub>1992     D. POYER *Circle*
> xxvi. 508   The motor died immediately after we lowered and we were
> carried away by the wind.</sub>
>
> **II.** Senses relating to degree, quality, or amount.
>
> **6.**
> **c.** *intransitive*. To descend to a lower rank, station, or standard of behaviour; to descend to a person's level. Now *rare*.
> <sub>1958     *Jewish Social Stud.* 20 141     It
> means rather lowering to the level of the congregation than raising
> them to his level.</sub>
> **7.**
> **b.** *intransitive*. Of a commodity, product, etc.: to decrease in price or value. Also with *in*, †*of*, or complement. Opposed to RISE
> *v.* 23c.
>  <sub>1794     W. HUTCHINSON *Hist. Cumberland* II. 665     Lamb..continues lowering in value as it becomes
> less rare.</sub>
>    <sub>1999     A. CARTER *Radical
> Green Polit. Theory* ii. 30     The production costs will
> fall and the innovative product will lower in price.</sub>
>
> **8.**
> **d.** *intransitive*. To become less intense; to diminish.
>  <sub>2010     *Times* (N. Ireland ed.) (Nexis) 7 Apr. 7
>    With every word, our spirits lowered.</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>